# Create a standalone groovy script with dependencies

Tags: maven, groovy, uberjar

I have a Groovy script with dependencies to RestFB:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
  <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I need to run this script on another machine with a **groovy-shell**. When I do it at the moment I get following error:

```
 @ line 7, column 1.
   import com.restfb.json.ParseException
   ^

1 error
```

I read about ways to build a uber-jar but never found a good example that shows how to do it. A step by step guide on how to approach this solution would be very helpful.

### Szymon Stepniak's answer

I used `@Grab` and it worked fine at first on my development machine. When I switched to my server the following happens:

```
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/report/ResolveReport
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/report/ResolveReport
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport
```

I understand that I at least need this ivy dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.ivy</groupId>
  <artifactId>ivy</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But how should I add it so the script can use it?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any fat jar if it comes to scripting in Groovy with dependencies. Groovy has a built-in mechanism called [**Grape**](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html) that allows you to bring maven dependencies to your script. All you have to do is use `@Grab('dependency_def')` annotation in the beginning of the script and that's it:

*script.groovy*

```
@Grab('com.restfb:restfb:2.0.0')

import com.restfb.json.ParseException

// do your stuff
```

Now you can run your script with:

```
groovy script.groovy
```

First run always takes more time, because Grape resolves and downloads dependencies. Next run is executed a few times faster, because dependencies are already downloaded.

Groovy scripts with `@Grab` annotation can be also run easily in IDE, e.g. IntelliJ IDEA has a built-in option to grab annotation and add them to the current project classpath: move cursor to `@Grab` annotation, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and choose `Grab the artifacts` option.

> *Reference: [Dependency management with Grape](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html)*

Comment: Hey there!
That worked partwise! When I run the script on my server still one error appears. Please see my edit!

Comment: @xetra11 Have tried adding this dependency to your script as `@Grab('org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.4.0')`? Grape allows you adding multiple dependencies.

Comment: yea I did so already. Nothing changes because I think the script needs this Classes to actually run the @Grab statements.

Comment: What groovy version you use on the server? Is it the same you use on your local machine?